# Zoom svg document in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, browser

I would like to present an svg document in my browser, however the problem is that there is no functionality available to the client with regard to zooming in or selecting part of the image. Therefore I presume that I have to embed the svg in a html page and use javascript to provide this functionality. What library would you recommend for conveniently providing such an interface?

Comment: Member for 9 years with 9k+ rep. You _must_ know software recommendation questions are off topic.

Answer (score 1):

[D3](https://d3js.org/) recommended lib for zooming/panning SVGs, note that this code snippet using v3 and the latest version of d3 is 5.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
      body, html {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
      }
      svg {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
      }
      p {
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Use the mouse to pan (click and move) / zoom (scrollwheel)</p>
  </body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var svg = d3.select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", "100%")
      .attr("height", "100%")
      .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", function () {
        svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")
      }))
      .append("g")

    svg.append("circle")
      .attr("cx", document.body.clientWidth / 2)
      .attr("cy", document.body.clientHeight / 2)
      .attr("r", 50)
      .style("fill", "#B8DEE6")
  </script>
</html>
```